# ¿Cómo seleccionar el último elemento de una clase?

Tags: html, css, css3

Tengo el siguiente código que muestra una lista de datos:

```css
.datos div {
  display:inline-block;
}

.contenedor { 
  margin:20px 40px; 
}

.contenedor:first-of-type { 
  margin-left: 10px; 
}

.contenedor:last-of-type { 
  margin-right: 10px; 
}

.separador {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height:10px;
}

.separador:last-child { 
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="datos">
  <div class="contenedor">DATO1</div>
  <div class="separador"></div>
  <div class="contenedor">DATO2</div>
  <div class="separador"></div>
  <div class="contenedor">DATO3</div>
  <div class="separador"></div>
</div>
```

El código HTML lo genera una aplicación que no puedo modificar, pero sí tengo acceso a cambiar el CSS. Consigo esconder la última barra vertical poniendo `.separador:last-child { display:none; }` pero sigo teniendo un problema: el último elemento con la clase contenedor tiene demasiado margen en la derecha.

He intentado hacer `.contenedor:last-of-type { margin-right: 10px; }` pero parece que `last-of-type` no funciona cuando se utiliza con una clase. ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar ese elemento para ponerle un margen derecho de 10px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si siempre vas a tener esa estructura `contenedor-separador-contenedor-separador` hay una solución. El último "contenedor" siempre será el penúltimo elemento de la serie y puedes usar la pseudo-clase `nth-last-child`:

> **NOTA:** Como ha indicado @Ricky_Ruiz en los comentarios para seleccionar el penúltimo elemento la sintaxis correcta es `nth-last-child(2)` y no `nth-last-child(-n+2)` como había puesto yo que selecciona los dos últimos elementos y parecía que funcionaba porque casualmente el último elemento estaba oculto.

```css
.datos div {
  display:inline-block;
}

.contenedor { 
  margin:20px 40px; 
}

.contenedor:first-of-type { 
  margin-left: 10px; 
}

.datos :nth-last-child(2) { 
  color: red; 
}

.separador {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height:10px;
}

.separador:last-child { 
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="datos">
  <div class="contenedor">DATO1</div>
  <div class="separador"></div>
  <div class="contenedor">DATO2</div>
  <div class="separador"></div>
  <div class="contenedor">DATO3</div>
  <div class="separador"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto es lo que buscaba, porque el número de datos es variable; entonces funciona independientemente del número de contenedores-separadores que tenga

Comment: El selector realmente sería `:nth-last-child(2)`, tal como está selecciona los últimos dos elementos de la lista, pero como el último hijo tiene `display: none;` no afecta.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz tienes razón, luego lo corrijo

Answer (score 2):

`last-of-type` solamente sirve para seleccionar el último elemento de ese tipo (`div`) del contenedor, no importa la clase que tiene.  Para seleccionarlo, debes usar [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

```css
.datos div {
  display:inline-block;
}

.contenedor { 
  margin:20px 40px; 
}

.contenedor:first-of-type { 
  margin-left: 10px; 
}

.contenedor:nth-child(5) { 
  margin-right: 10px; 
}

.separador {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height:10px;
}

.separador:last-child { 
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="datos">
  <div class="contenedor">DATO1</div>
  <div class="separador"></div>
  <div class="contenedor">DATO2</div>
  <div class="separador"></div>
  <div class="contenedor">DATO3</div>
  <div class="separador"></div>
</div>
```

Tendrías que cambiar el número dentro de los paréntesis para que esté de acuerdo con el número de elementos que tienes, y si la estructura siempre va a ser lo mismo, la respuesta de @blonfu también es otra opción que, en ese caso, sería mejor.